# Maui - Barcode scanning

Tags: maui, barcode, zxing, zxing.net

I am searching for a barcode scanning library for my MAUI project. In Xamarin, I previously utilized Zxing, but unfortunately, Zxing for MAUI does not currently support the Windows platform. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Camera.MAUI](https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI) plugin which also leverages ZXing but supports Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get something working with the [BarcodeScanner.Mobile.UI](https://github.com/JimmyPun610/BarcodeScanner.Mobile) library. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWP2t-B5ADU) on how to implement it by Gerald Versluis.

The standard implementation in .net 8 will throw an error due to the way the nuget package unpacks the google libraries BUT there is an explanation and fix for the issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/800).